# How can i load image to pictureBox from string array the last index file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried this:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(combinedsatelliteimagesdir);
NumericComparer ns = new NumericComparer();
Array.Sort(files, ns);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(files[files.Length -1]);
```

But i'm getting out of memory exception on the line:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(files[files.Length -1]);
```

the variable files contain 847 indexs for example the first index look like:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\satelliteImages\SatImage0.GIF

Comment: that simply means there no file in your `combinedsatelliteimagesdir` directory. Might be you are searching for files with pattern and that search is returning No Files.

Comment: I recommend storing the last element from the array and have a look at it in debugger. string temp = files[files.Length -1]);

Comment: I tried using the temp and what i see in temp is: C:\Users\chocolade1972\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\satelliteImages\Thumbs.db and i checked now more and more i don't see this file in this directory. Only images files.

Comment: And now i added a filter: string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(combinedsatelliteimagesdir,"*.GIF"); so now temp show the last file and it's image. I just wonder where this Thumbs.db came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx), you get `OutOfMemoryException` if

> The file does not have a valid image format.
>
> -or-
>
> GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

You probably reading some *non-image* file.

---

Regarding `thumbs.db`:

> Thumbs.db is an image cache which makes thumbnail viewing faster. The file is automatically created in Windows Vista, 7 and 8 whenever images are encountered in a folder. It's usually hidden but can appear, disappear and is often impossible to delete

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@files[files.Length - 1]);
```

By the way, are you sure that last file is every time a picture? No hidden "desktop.ini" or something else?